# Elegantly combine list of records into JSON for a Python post request?

Tags: python, json

I'm parsing a Pandas DataFrame table for an API post request (using requests, of course). I'm working on building my script in Jupyter Notebooks.

```
result = df.to_json(orient="records")
parsed_json = json.loads(result)
```

I've seen a lot of JSON manipulations with `format()`, so my first impulse was to use f-strings:

```
je_json = json.dumps({
    'BatchId': '1',
    'userId': 'myID',
    'journalEntries': f'{parsed_json }'
})
```

It would be very readable and elegant, but of course it doesn't work as the result is escaped and will not POST:

```
'{"BatchId": "1", "userId": "myID", "journalEntries": "[{\\"JENumber\\":\\"PR2022-01-23\\",\\"Date\\":\\"01\\\\/23\\\\/2022\\",\\"JEComment\\": [...]
```

I solved the problem by reconstructing the list/dicts:

```
je_json = {
    'BatchId': '1',
    'userId': 'myID',
    'journalEntries': ''
}

je_json['journalEntries'] = []

for record in parsed_json:
    je_json['journalEntries'].append(record)

payload = json.dumps(je_json)
```

Is there a simpler or more elegant solution?

---

### Request

```
data_headers = {
    'Authorization': str(parsed_data.get('BearerToken')),
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Cookie': 'ss-opt=temp; ss-pid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
}

response = requests.request(method="POST", 
    url=URL, 
    headers=data_headers, 
    data=payload)
```

### Explanation of my testing methodology

Since running tests in Jupyter notebooks can be tricky, I'm going to mention here my methodology. Right now, I'm ***testing the payload variable and request*** in a separate cells. After a successful record insertion via the API, I don't reload the whole notebook, and simply reload the payload and request cells: 1) Change the successful payload cell into type 'raw'; 2) Add new cell with modified payload variable for testing; 3) reload the payload and request cells; 4) examine the results; 5) toggle cell type 'code' and 'raw' to return to the success version and verify underlying code; 6) repeat. What makes this work is toggling cell type, and never ***mutating variables*** once assigned--there is no assignment to any variable name assigned to a cell above it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I fail to see a reason for the long way around.
If you already have parsed JSON, why not use it directly?

```py
result = df.to_json(orient="records")
parsed_json = json.loads(result)

je_json = json.dumps({
    'BatchId': '1',
    'userId': 'myID',
    'journalEntries': parsed_json
})
```

It would be even better to not serialize and deserialize the JSON data twice:

```py
je_json = json.dumps({
    'BatchId': '1',
    'userId': 'myID',
    'journalEntries': df.to_dict(orient="records")
})
```

On a side-note I find it funny, how `pandas`' method name `to_dict()` is absolutely misleading, since it returns a `list` in the above case.

Also, you don't need to serialize the JSON payload manually, since `requests` will do it for you:

```py
from requests import post


payload = {
    'BatchId': '1',
    'userId': 'myID',
    'journalEntries': df.to_dict(orient="records")
}

response = post('https://yourapp.com/submit', json=payload)
```

Comment: #1 & #2 worked perfectly. Exactly what I hoped for. Example #3 didn't work without `json.dumps()` : `'{"ResponseStatus":{"ErrorCode":"SerializationException","Message":"Could not deserialize \'application/json\'`; Maybe something to do with my request? I posted this line above.

Comment: Ok. Just to be clear. With `json.dumps()` everything works as expected. Help me out here. I'm a noob with JSON and REST. Can I arrive at the same conclusion if, say, I read the [requests docs](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) from start to finish?

Comment: @xtian They should both work, i.e. a POST request with `data=json.dumps(payload)` and `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` passed in explicitly as one of the headers is equivalent to a request with just `json=payload`, where the header is set for you in the latter case (see examples at the end of [More complicated POST requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)). I would double-check your request that uses `json=` to make sure you're not overlooking anything.

Comment: > _"double-check your request that uses `json=`.."_ That's it. I need to ***read a good book on requests***, because that was just not *obvious*--until you pointed it out.